# ipad can i edit the master view on splitView template

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, ipad

I have used the template from ipad to create a splitView app but the master view provided is quite big for what i need and is would be nice if i could place some pictures on the top of the list.

Is it possible to editing the size of the master view? 
i read in some old questions (a year or more) that that is not a good practice for apple. what about sdk 5 now ?

In the master view we usually have a root navigator, is it possible to move the bar to the bottom so i can have some image on the top?

dont want to have a app rejected from apple and a angry boss :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if the [excellent Matt Gemmell implementation](http://mattgemmell.com/2010/07/31/mgsplitviewcontroller-for-ipad/) of the split view controller will meet your needs.

The version that comes from GitHub has some warning it will throw. To fix the "Semantic Issue" warnings you can do update the code to read like this:

```
//Line 940 and line 984 of MGSplitViewController.m
return [(UIViewController *)[controller retain] autorelease];
```

The other issue you get when you first start the project is fixed by clicking the "Validate Settings" button on the project Summary page or `Editor` menu choose `Validate Settings...`

Comment: i was trying to use it but when i import his sample i get errors of configuration which i need to learn more deeply. But is it possible to change the template on new sdk?

Comment: I updated my answer to deal with the warnings you probably saw.

Comment: i imported the MG classes on one split template, changed the delegated as demo demonstrate and that doesn't give me any error. Then i run it and get the following msg, 
2011-11-17 09:42:44.701 splitWithMGS[3281:207] -[RootViewController selectFirstRow]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x525d250
2011-11-17 09:42:44.704 splitWithMGS[3281:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[RootViewController selectFirstRow]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x525d250'

Comment: It is probably easier if you start with the MGSplitView demo project and import your views into it.

Comment: From the looks of your error it seems that you added the MGSplitViewController but did not also add the RootViewController and DetailViewController's from the Demo project.